# TableRow OnClickListener's getId returns -1 - What gives?

Tags: android

I'm creating tablerows programmatically, and I'm trying to implement an OnClickListener:

```
            final TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setId(tourney.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            tr.setClickable(true);

            tr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    System.out.println("Row clicked: " + v.getId());

                }
            });
```

But everytime I click on the row, I get a value of -1.  Why am I not getting the id that I set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I was getting -1 on getId was because of this line:

```
tr.setId(tourney.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

"_id" was not a part of the query, so I was not getting the column index.  Even then, it wasn't the value I really wanted, but this fixed my issue:

```
tr.setId(tourney.getInt(tourney.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TableRow object is conforming to OOP standards, it should only be aware of it´s own state, not it´s position in another object. Instead, you should grab a reference to your TableLayout, and then call `indexOfChild(View child)` on it:

```
TableLayout tblLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourTableLayout);
int tableRowIndex = tblLayout.indexOfChild(tr);
```

Comment: Based on what you wrote,  `System.out.println("Row clicked 2: " + myTL.getChildAt(tableRowIndex).getId());` still returns -1.

Comment: Well of course, you are basically just doing what you did above, which is calling getId() on your TableRow object. It´s the tableRowIndex you want to use.

Comment: tableRowIndex does not give me what I need.  I answered my own problem by giving myself an answer, which was the "_id" field was not present in the SQL query I made, which gave me the -1 value.